# Parsing a 64bit number into 16bit parts, doesn't work intuitively [solved]

Tags: c++, bit-manipulation

I have a string, consisting of 8 chars.

```
std::string input = { 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'A', 'F' };
```

I have a 64 bit integer which will hold the hexadecimal correspondence of this string. And four 16 bit integers, which the number will be parsed into.

```
uint64_t number = 0;

uint16_t part0;
uint16_t part1;
uint16_t part2;
uint16_t part3;
```

I am converting string into a number using stringstream ( never used before )

```
std::stringstream ss;
ss << std::hex << input;
ss >> number;
```

I then AND the number with 0x000000FF, and right shift 16 bits.

```
part0 = number & 0x000000FF;  //output: AF
number >>= 16;

part1 = number & 0x000000FF;  //output: CD
number >>= 16;

part2 = number & 0x000000FF;  //output: 0
number >>= 16;

part3 = number & 0x000000FF;  //output: 0
```

However, even though string consists of 8 chars, the number is 64 bits, and parts are 16 bits, this just doesn't work when shifting 16 bits. Results are as I noted as comments. It obviously shifting twice as much than it should, so I tried shifting 8 bits, and it works as it supposed to. I am quite baffled, can someone explain why?

---

## edit:

As [john](https://stackoverflow.com/users/882003/john) pointed out in comments, one hexadecimal digit is 4 bits, not 8, as I thought. This was the problem.

Comment: The `0x000000FF` mask clears all but the low **eight** bits. For 16-bit components, you need a mask like `0x000000000000FFFFuLL`.

Comment: What is "a 64 bit integer which will hold the hexadecimal correspondence"? Most integers are binary, so if you mean some particular use of such an integer, it's not clear.

Comment: One hexadecimal digit is 4 bits. 8 hexadecimal digits is 32 bits not 64. Maybe that is your confusion?

Comment: @AdrianMole 0xFFFFu is enough ^^

Comment: @bruno I like to be explicitly precise!

Comment: @AdrianMole but nothing says `uint64_t` is `unsigned long long`, so better to not suppose

Comment: Instead of `stringstream` you could just say `number = strtoull(input.c_str(), nullptr, 16);`

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt I was trying to say that the string will be a hexadecimal value, not a random string, and number will hold it, not the best wording apparently.

Comment: @john, oh... I guess that is it... Thanks.

Comment: BTW: You say "doesn't work", but that's just an interpretation. You need to tell us what you observe and what you expected instead. For that, you have to provide a [mcve] though. Please also take the [tour] and read [ask].

Comment: @selbie I am going to try that. I just googled converting a string into integer and tried the first one.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt I explained what "doesn't work" meant. As //comments in the code, and pointed that comments was the explanation.

Comment: @bruno 1) `unsigned long long` is always >= 64bits, 2) forgetting `uLL` can cause alot of headache, especially when doing alot of bit manipulations. been there, done that. being explicit is definitely the way to go unless you have very special requirements.

Comment: @selbie I am now implementing the strtoull, however I am worried that my string not having a null terminator may cause a problem. Would that be the case? I don't know if std::string internally handles it, I am not quite familiar with standard containers.

Comment: @melonduofromage: `std::string` **always** has a null terminator.  When you invoke `.c_str()`, it gives you back the backing `char*` pointer which is null terminated, regardless of how you initialized it.